# how to display woocomerce description of each category in wordpress?

Tags: php, woocommerce-offtopic

```
         <ul>
<?php 
     $taxonomyName = "product_cat";
$prod_categories = get_terms($taxonomyName, array(
'orderby'=> 'name',
'order' => 'Desc',
'hide_empty' => 1,
));  
foreach( $prod_categories as $prod_cat ) :
if ( $prod_cat->parent != 0 )
    continue;
$cat_thumb_id = get_woocommerce_term_meta( $prod_cat->term_id, 'thumbnail_id', true );
$cat_thumb_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $cat_thumb_id, 'thumbnail-size' )[0];
$term_link = get_term_link( $prod_cat, 'product_cat' );
   ?>
```

```
<h2>02</h2>
    <h3><div class="cat"><div class="wrap_cat"><?php echo $prod_cat->name; ?> </div></div></h3>
    </span>
         <img src="<?php echo $cat_thumb_url; ?>" alt=""/>    
    <p><?php ?></p>
    <a href="<?php echo $term_link; ?>" class="trend_read_more"> Read More</a>
</li>      <?php endforeach; 
wp_reset_query(); ?>    
</ul>
```

> i want to display category discription inside the p tag , please help me if anybody know?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$args = array( 'taxonomy' => 'product_cat' );
$terms = get_terms('product_cat', $args);

$count = count($terms); 

if ($count > 0) {

    foreach ($terms as $term) {
        echo $term->description;

    }

}
```

Comment: how to add number of products counts in category  , ex: men(23)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Instead of just posting only code please provide more details about how this solves the problem.